# How to format the spaces between record fields below using bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

How to format the spaces between records below using bash:

```
 123  sample  file  456
 894  sample  files 789
```

to

```
 123   sample    file       456
 894   sample    files      789
```

where

```
 123 <3spaces> sample <4spaces> file <7spaces> 456
 894 <3spaces> sample <4spaces> files <6spaces> 789
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using awk with `printf`. To left-justify your columns you can use a minus sign in your format specifier:

```
awk '{printf "%-6s%-10s%-11s%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
```

The negative numbers specify the width of each column but the padding is to the right, rather than to the left.

Output:

```
123   sample    file       456
894   sample    files      789
```

Actually, you can do this in more or less exactly the same way using the bash built-in `printf` with `read`:

```
while read -ra cols; do printf "%-6s%-10s%-11s%s\n" "${cols[@]}"; done < file
```

The `-a` switch to `read` means that the columns are read into an array.

Comment: +1 for the awk solution but don't use the bash one as you're at risk for nasal demons if you do. The shell language is for sequencing calls to tools, not for manipulating text - that's why it's so cumbersome to do the latter robustly in shell. For example, try the awk and shell solutions with the 2nd field on line 1 of your input file set to `.*` instead of `sample`.

Comment: @Ed good point, I didn't test the bash version extensively. I have changed it now so it works with the input you suggested as well. I'm all in favour of using awk but it's nice to know what the shell can (and can't) do as well.

Comment: the thing is the shell CAN do just about anything so now what? The only thing that matters is what SHOULD you do in the shell - once you understand that then the purpose for not only the shell but also the other standard UNIX tools becomes glaringly clear and you no longer find yourself wondering which similar-seeming tools or shell builtins to use for whatever problem you're tackling.